# matplotlib spectrogram, intensity scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I want to plot two spectrograms side by side, and compare them. For the comparison to make sense, they need to have the same scale on the intensity axis.

There does not seem to be anything like `zlim` for me to get the scaling to be the same.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Wait...are you plotting in 3d and want them to have the same z-axis? Or in 2d and want them so have the same color? Because you can just [call `set_zlim`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_zlim) on the axex of a 3d plot. And (depending on the actual plot command) you can pass `vmin` and `vmax` as arguments to scale the color bar range.

Comment: I call the intensity a "third dimension", although it is a 2D plot. `clim` solved the problem. The question referenced by @Carsten is similar, but using `imshow` and not `specgram`. In the end it's the same, but I didn't think of searching for this issue with `imshow`, which is why I didn't find it.